# ng2-smart-table use the space where "add" button is for "select columns" button

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

The place where the "Add" button is located seems wrong, on the other hand it is a good place for "Columns selection" button that will open a dialog that will allow the users to select which columns to see and which to hide

This is the relevant code changes that i have made to the settings configuration:

```
actions: { 
          columnTitle: 'Actions',
          class: 'actions-area',
          add: true,              
        },    
        add: {
          addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-gear" title="select columns"></i>',
          createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
          cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
        },
```

So this code above only replaces the icon from the "+" icon to the "gear" icon

See image

[image]

Now i want this button to call my on function and not to the default function that adds a row to the table, since what i really want to do is not related to the "add" functionality
i just need the asset space for it

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation

You need to change your mode configuration to External

[Then use this event to access that button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28pzr.png)

[Then you add the event to the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywgXP.png)

And finally you add your function to your ts.

```
youFunction(){
  //your code here
}
```